# Flash_image clockworkmod recovery for Samsung Fascinate

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, samsung-fascinate

I have a Samsung Fascinate for a while that I've wanted to flash a new rom to, but the USB port simply will not work on any PC. I've tried it on 6 different PC's with a mixture of XP / 7 along with numerous installations and reinstallations of the Fascinate drivers. It charges but will not be recognized by the Windows, Odin or Heimdall, so I've given up in that respect.

However, the phone IS rooted. I know this because I can give su permissions and I'm seeing the # in the terminal emulator. So I would like to know if I can get clockworkmod recovery onto it through the "flash_image" command - I've seen tutorials for other phones that are able to do this.

However another problem is that I can find no .img Clockwork recovery files for the Fascinate anywhere. I can find the .zip that's provided on Rom Manager's website (and also the .zip downloaded by Rom Manager itself), but I'm not sure if that's the same thing as a .img.

So my question is, can I flash a .zip as a recovery image? If not, is there some kind of directory of official Clockworkmod recovery .img files, or at least one for the Fascinate somewhere? If not, can I take a .tar or a .bin and somehow mess with those files on the Fascinate without having to utilize Odin / Heimdall?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Does ROM Manager not provide the option to flash it for you? I know it does on other devices, but I've never tried on a Fascinate.

Comment: Flashing a .zip is easier than flashing a .img unless Koush simplified the process for the latter.  Try XDA if you want a Fascinate-specific version of CWM, I think the official one deals with the internal/external SD improperly due to the way Samsung mounts it.  That's the case with my Vibrant, anyways.